# tkinter, creating a grid of 12 buttons from a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tkinter

I am trying to create a grid of 12 buttons from a list of 3 items. Currently the code runs and create the 12 buttons in the grid, but each button is the last item in the list. Not sure how to store or save the list item for each row.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

testList = ['Boop','Yeet','Noop']


nrows = 4
ncols = 3
for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):
        for i in testList:
            tk.Button(text=i,padx=50, pady=50).grid(row = r, column=c)



root.mainloop()
```

Current output is a grid with 4 columns of 3 rows each with the word Noop on it.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXwmO.png)

Comment: You are creating 36 buttons here - for each combination of `r` and `c`, you are creating one button with each string from `testList`, all three being placed at the same grid location so that only the final one is visible.  It's not clear just how you want the buttons to be named, but perhaps get rid of the `for i` loop, and using `text=testList[c]` when creating the Button.

Comment: That fixed it. Knew it was something simple like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your loop is actually running 36 times.  For each r and c, it runs through all three words in the list and makes a button and replaces the previous one leaving you with the last word in all places.
My best guess is that you were trying to do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

testList = ['Boop','Yeet','Noop']

nrows = 4
ncols = 3
for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):
        tk.Button(text=testList[c],padx=50, pady=50).grid(row = r, column=c)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to "debug", you can print out what's happening:

```
print("row " + str(r) + ", col " + str(c) + ", item " + i)
```

You get this output:

```
row 0, col 0, item Boop
row 0, col 0, item Yeet
row 0, col 0, item Noop

row 0, col 1, item Boop
row 0, col 1, item Yeet
row 0, col 1, item Noop

row 0, col 2, item Boop
row 0, col 2, item Yeet
row 0, col 2, item Noop

row 1, col 0, item Boop
row 1, col 0, item Yeet
row 1, col 0, item Noop

row 1, col 1, item Boop
row 1, col 1, item Yeet
row 1, col 1, item Noop

row 1, col 2, item Boop
row 1, col 2, item Yeet
row 1, col 2, item Noop

row 2, col 0, item Boop
row 2, col 0, item Yeet
row 2, col 0, item Noop

row 2, col 1, item Boop
row 2, col 1, item Yeet
row 2, col 1, item Noop

row 2, col 2, item Boop
row 2, col 2, item Yeet
row 2, col 2, item Noop

row 3, col 0, item Boop
row 3, col 0, item Yeet
row 3, col 0, item Noop

row 3, col 1, item Boop
row 3, col 1, item Yeet
row 3, col 1, item Noop

row 3, col 2, item Boop
row 3, col 2, item Yeet
row 3, col 2, item Noop
```

For every row, for every column in the row, you're setting the values of `testList`, the last one being `'Noop'`.

---

I'm not sure what you want to do, as it is not clear in this question, but if you want every row to have the three items, you need to iterate over every row, then for every column, give it the corresponding value of `testList`, which is `testList[c]`:

```
for r in range(nrows):
    for c in range(ncols):
        print("row " + str(r) + ", col " + str(c) + ", item " + testList[c])
        tk.Button(text=testList[c],padx=50, pady=50).grid(row = r, column=c)
```

The output becomes:

```
row 0, col 0, item Boop
row 0, col 1, item Yeet
row 0, col 2, item Noop

row 1, col 0, item Boop
row 1, col 1, item Yeet
row 1, col 2, item Noop

row 2, col 0, item Boop
row 2, col 1, item Yeet
row 2, col 2, item Noop

row 3, col 0, item Boop
row 3, col 1, item Yeet
row 3, col 2, item Noop
```

---

Edit: I was already writing my answer when jasonharper commented. Nothing stolen here!